# Have sshd forward logins of git user to a (GitLab) Docker container

Tags: git, ssh, docker, gitlab, sshd

I would like to configure sshd on my host machine to forward public key logins of a certain user to a Docker container that runs its own sshd service.

To give some context, I have GitLab running in a Docker container and I dislike opening another port on the host machine for the SSH GitLab communication but instead have sshd on the host machine redirect user and key directly to the port the GitLab exposes on the local machine.

My idea is to do something like this:

```
Match User git
  ForceCommand ssh -p <GitLab port> <some arguments that forward to> git@localhost
  ...
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a simple workaround to this. Just create a Git user on the host machine and provide a proxy script that executes the given Git commands in the GitLab container using the host's SSH daemon and the `.ssh/authorized_keys` from the container volume.

1. On the host machine, add the user `git` using the same UID & GID as in the GitLab docker container (998) and set your GitLab `data` directory as the user's home:

   ```
   useradd -u 998 -s /bin/bash -d /your/gitlab/path/data git
   ```
2. Add the `git` user to the docker group

   ```
   usermod -G docker git
   ```
3. Add a proxy script `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell` on the host machine with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   docker exec -i -u git <your_gitlab_container_id> sh -c "SSH_CONNECTION='$SSH_CONNECTION' SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND' $0 $1"
   ```

Comment: I have added `--env="USERMAP_UID=$((id git -u)) --env="USERMAP_GID=$((id git -g))"` to the docker run command to avoid using weird uid/gid (i have added classic user, without -u 998)

Comment: You need to use `docker exec -i -u git <gitlab_container> sh -c ...` otherwise the git repositories will be accessed (and modified) as `root`. This will actually work but eventually you will run into problems (e.g. when you try to edit a file in a repository with Gitlab web interface).

Comment: What do you mean by GitLab data directory? `/var/opt/gitlab` ?

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that the hosts "git" user is in the docker group which is problematic from a security perspective.

Comment: I would like to try this, but I first would like to understand the third step. Could you elaborate on what it does? Is it still expected to work after all these years?  In my system, the closest path I have is `/opt/gitlab/data/gitlab-shell/` and there is no `bin` directory in there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing would make the users required to authenticate twice. Once with your server and for the second time to your gitlab in docker, which is basically something you don't want.

When you mention public key authentication, it would require to share the authorized keys file or command from your gitlab with your host machine somehow.

I believe it is possible, but much easier is to open that port.

From the client side, you can do the same with `ProxyCommand` like this:

```
Hostname your-gitlab
  ProxyCommand ssh -W localhost:<GitLab port> git@your-git-host
```

Comment: i wonder if git would work using that. you know.. gitlab provides git hosting. i seriously wonder if this would work then: `git clone your-gitlab:foo/bar.git`

Comment: @GottZ why not? Have you tried? It is common practice for multi-hop routes.

Comment: @Jakuje, you may be right: It would result in authenticating twice. I could live with that but I don't see an easy way of sharing the authorized_keys files. Accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to push my git repos through my host into a docker machine.
I played a little with the ForceCommand option.
This works for me ;)

```
Match User git
  ForceCommand ssh git@localhost -p 9022 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

Comment: Tried this, did not work.   Did you do this in SSHD on your docker host side...or on your client side (where your local repo sits)?

Comment: This method does not work, as it does not forward the public key to the ssh server running on port 9022.

Comment: This works, but there is catch : you need to add "ForwardAgent yes" on the client side .ssh/config file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @kwizzn's solution is to forward all GitLab SSH interactions to GitLab container like [documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup.html) (together with [Git protocol v2](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/git_protocol.html)). In this solution we let Git instance to check the SSH keys with container's `gitlab-shell-authorized-keys-check` command and modify the returned `command` statement (see `gitlab-auth.sh` script) to run within the docker container (see `gitlab-exec.sh` script).

Use user `root` to create files and to run all commands.

So let's say we have a container named `gitlab-web` running GitLab instance:

1. Add `git` user to the host machine:

   ```bash
   mkdir --parents /var/lib/git
   useradd --system --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --home-dir /var/lib/git --groups docker git
   ```
2. Create script at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-auth.sh` and make it executable (`chmod ugo+x /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-auth.sh`) - this will be executed as `root` user before authentication:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   docker exec -i -u git \
       gitlab-web \
       /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell-authorized-keys-check git "$@" | \
       sed -E "s#(command=\")#\\1/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-exec.sh #"
   ```
3. Create script at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-exec.sh` and make it executable (`chmod ugo+x /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-exec.sh`) - this will be executed as `git` user after SSH authentication:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   docker exec -i -u git \
       -e "GIT_PROTOCOL=$GIT_PROTOCOL" \
       -e "SSH_CONNECTION=$SSH_CONNECTION" \
       -e "SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" \
       gitlab-web \
       "$@"
   ```
4. Create `sshd` configuration for `git` user at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/git.conf`:

   ```
   Match User git
     AcceptEnv GIT_PROTOCOL
     AuthenticationMethods publickey
     DisableForwarding yes
     PermitTTY no
     PermitTunnel no
     PermitUserRC no
     AuthorizedKeysCommand /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/gitlab-auth.sh %u %k
     AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
   ```
5. Ensure the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/git.conf` is loaded from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Check that line is there or add it if it is not:

   ```
   Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another (untested) possibility could be that you forward the connection from the host into the container by adding it to the authorized_keys file of the git user as such:

```
command="nc -q0 gitlab 22" ssh-rsa AAAAB....[REST OF YOUR PUBKEY]
```

The git user should be created on the host machine. now when you connect with "ssh git@host", this connection should be forwarded with "nc" to the gitlab container.

Obviously that also requires to have all the gitlab ssh keys copied with the *command* prefix to the host machine

However this works only if the gitlab container is **not** in an isolated network and the host container has actually the possibility to connect to the gitlab port 22.

In my setup, this did not work since gitlab is in an isolated network, so I ended up running gitlab ssh on another port:

- Start the container with `-p 20022:22`
- add `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 20022` to your gitlab.rb config

Comment: This looked promising - but when I tried it, git receives SSH protocol data instead of what it expects.